# Wifi not connected in fedora?

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, fedora-16

I have installed fedora 16 and it initially shows me 'firmware missing' in wireless network. Then I have searched in google and find the solution that is I installed broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5 and the wireless network started to show the wireless network.

Now my problem is not that it doesn't show wireless networks. It shows all networks and when I try to connect it only says connecting and after sometimes connection failed.I have tried many times but nothing happened. I am suffering from this problem from last 6 months.

I think the wirelss networks themselves have no problem because even not only my other friends are using those networks but myself in windows is using those networks. I have to search these fedora problems first in windows and I have to proceed it into fedora after that. That is, my main problem is, never can get connected with wireless network, what can I do ?

Does anyone have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=239922) is a fantastic guide for walking through how to identify, install and configure Broadcom Wireless drivers. Check it out.